# Ricardian contracts

Tags: smart-contract, ricardian

At what level are Ricardian contracts implemented? Examples I see are in the constitution . Can these be applied at the application level? Eg. A derivation contract with the terms of  contract richardian?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can create a dapp with a Ricardian contract embedded in it. Specifically in the abi file which is a JSON file defining the interface of the smart contract or the dapp. This is the empty Ricardian structure:

```
"ricardian_clauses": []
```

A more elaborate example of a ricardian contract can be seen in the [hello](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/hello/hello.abi) example contract.

A Ricardian contract states the intentions of the contract and can reference actual code from the dapp.
More info can be found in: [Ricardian contracts — legally binding agreements on the blockchain](https://medium.com/legalthingsone/ricardian-contracts-legally-binding-agreements-on-the-blockchain-4c103f120707)

Comment: The hello example was probably taken from a BP contract and is not really adjusted to the hello example. There should be more as it is a proposed requirement of the constitution to publish source code and ricardian contracts of dApps on EOS.

Comment: @friedger, I agree with the proposal, transparency is a great requirement and ricardian contracts both help and need the source code of the contracts. My answer was on the technical aspects of the issue, not the content. You're more than welcome to write a better answer :)

Comment: Your answer is good! The hello is the only example I could find as well. I tried to write some for monstereos: https://github.com/leordev/monstereos/tree/master/contracts/pet